# Frequency of Chars

Tags: c++, char, counting

I'm close to finishing my code! I could use some assistance, I've wrote a program that will count the number of letters in a string. My problem comes at the end, when outputting my data. say I enter the string "AAAABBBC"

My expected output should be
A-4
B-3
C-1

instead I get
C-4
C-3
C-1

any help would be appreciated, my code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




class moose
{
    char inputbuffer[122];
    char countbuffer[122];
    long count;
    short index = 0;

public:
    char charcount();
    char charinput();
    char initialize();

};

int main()
{
    moose obj;
    obj.initialize();
    obj.charinput();
    obj.charcount();
    system("pause");

}


char moose::initialize()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 122; i++) 
        countbuffer[i] = 0;

    return 0;

}

char moose::charinput()
{
    cout << "Enter your text and I'll read your characters" << endl;
    cin.getline(inputbuffer, 132);
    cin.gcount();
    count = cin.gcount();
    count--;
    return 0;
}

char moose::charcount()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (inputbuffer[i] >= 'a' & inputbuffer[i] <= 'z' || inputbuffer[i] >= 'A' & inputbuffer[i] <= 'Z' || inputbuffer[i] > '0' & inputbuffer[i] <= '9'){
            index = inputbuffer[i];
            countbuffer[index]++;

        }


    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= 122; i++) {
        if (countbuffer[i] > 0)
        {
            cout << char(index) << " - " << int(countbuffer[i]) << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Read the variable names in the last loop carefully.

Comment: Improve general quality of code: if method returns nothing, set void, couter (I guess) as integer. Use constant in place 122 etc

Comment: Welp, I've read Eric Lippert's blog, and although it was good and I can apply it to my future projects,  I don't think it has the answers to my questions. I'm new to programming, a lot of this is still foreign and hard to process so I've come to a forum for some assistance, what a sin. I will continue to troubleshoot as I have for the past few hours.

Answer (score 2):

```
char moose::charcount()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (inputbuffer[i] >= 'a' && inputbuffer[i] <= 'z' || inputbuffer[i] >= 'A' && inputbuffer[i] <= 'Z' || inputbuffer[i] > '0' && inputbuffer[i] <= '9'){
            index = inputbuffer[i];
            countbuffer[index]++;

        }


    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= 122; i++) {
        if (countbuffer[i] > 0)
        {
            cout << char(i) << " - " << int(countbuffer[i]) << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

1. Print "i" in place of index.
2. & - bitwise-AND, use &&

Answer (score 1):

Modify the last loop like in the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 122; i++) {
    if (countbuffer[i] > 0)
    {
        cout << char(i) << " - " << int(countbuffer[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

And convert bitwise ands to logical ands in the first loop (use &&).

By the way, in your case it is better to use a STL container like unordered_map, since you are going to build a histogram of characters actually. If you are going to store the frequency for a few characters in general, it is wasteful to allocate an array indexed by all possible characters, since a lot of the entries will be 0 in the end.

Comment: Hey Thanks! that was a simple fix. I'm not sure what you mean by STL container, I will read up on that. really appreciate the help!